# How to select the highest value and subtract the lower values from Postgresql nested query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, subquery

This is what I'm trying to achieve - say I have an integer column with people's ages for instance, I want to select the highest age and get it's difference with the other selected ages. So if I do:

```
SELECT ages FROM people
ORDER BY ages DESC
```

And get `30 25 20 15 10` for example, I'd like to do another `SELECT` that will perform `30-30, 30-25, 30-20, 30-15, 30-10`

```
SELECT --how do I perform that here? 
FROM (  
    SELECT ages FROM peoeple
    ORDER BY ages DESC
)foo
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery that returns the max age:

```
select (select max(age) from people) - age
from people
order by 1 -- ordering is optional, but it seems you want data in this order
```

---

btw, `age` is a better name for someone's age than `ages`.

Comment: I was sure the answer was pretty straight forward, I don't know how I missed this. Thanks, it's just what I needed